# Como hago para que el UPDATE QUERY funcione con el response?

Tags: php, mysql, android

Necesito que por favor me echen la mano en esto, estoy realizando una aplicacion de inventario y necesito que modifique los productos, pero de la manera que estaba anteriormente permitia modificarlos aun si los campos iban vacios y no lanzaba un error de que los datos eran incorrectos, en todo momento decia que fue modificado con exito, y no me sirve asi, entonces lei que necesito meterle response y JSON para eso, y lo hice, pero no me funciona, no modifica, en que me puedo estar equivocando?

Le adjunto el codigo:

```
    <?php   

      $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "contrumeca");

      $codproducto = $_POST["codproducto"];
      $nombre_producto = $_POST["nombre_producto"];
      $margen_utilidad = $_POST["margen_utilidad"];
      $unidad_manejo = $_POST["unidad_manejo"];
      $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
      $proveedor = $_POST["proveedor"];
      $precio = $_POST["precio"];
      $existencia = $_POST["existencia"];
      $tipo_producto = $_POST["tipo_producto"];

      $statement = mysqli_prepare($conexion, "UPDATE producto SET nombre_producto = '".$nombre_producto."', margen_utilidad = '".$margen_utilidad."', unidad_manejo = '".$unidad_manejo."', descripcion = '".$descripcion."', proveedor = '".$proveedor."', precio ='".$precio."', existencia = '".$existencia."', tipo_producto = '".$tipo_producto."' WHERE codproducto = '".$codproducto."'");

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "isissidis", $codproducto, $nombre_producto, $margen_utilidad, $unidad_manejo, $descripcion, $proveedor, $precio, $existencia, $tipo_producto);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

      //Declarar el response *//

      $response = array();
      $response["success"] = false;

      while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;  
        $response["nombre_producto"] = $nombre_producto;
        $response["margen_utilidad"] = $margen_utilidad;
        $response["unidad_manejo"] = $unidad_manejo;
        $response["descripcion"] = $descripcion;
        $response["proveedor"] = $proveedor;
        $response["precio"] = $precio;
        $response["existencia"] = $existencia;
        $tipo_producto["tipo_producto"] = $tipo_producto;
    }

      echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

No me funciona, estoy trabajando en un aplicativo y necesito que me aparezca un error cuando los campos vayan vacios o llenos, todo el tiempo ejecuta asi sea esten vacios, y no me sirve asi.

El codigo de Android es:

```
modificar_producto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            final String nombre_articulo = nombre_producto.getText().toString();
                            final int texto_margen_utilidad = Integer.parseInt(margen_utilidad.getText().toString());
                            final String texto_unidad_manejo = unidad_manejo.getText().toString();
                            final String descripcion_articulo = descripcion_producto.getText().toString();
                            final int proveedor = Integer.parseInt(proveedor_producto.getText().toString());
                            final int precio_articulo = Integer.parseInt(precio_producto.getText().toString());
                            final int existencia_articulo = Integer.parseInt(existencia_producto.getText().toString());
                            final String tipo_productop = tipo_producto.getText().toString();


                            Response.Listener<String> respoListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {

                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                                        if(success)
                                        {

                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Producto Modificado Correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        }else
                                        {

                                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Modificar_Producto.this);
                                            builder.setMessage("Error N°000000000000000000").setNegativeButton("Retirar mensaje", null).create().show();

                                        }

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            };

                            Solicitud_Actualizar_Producto solicitud_actualizar_producto = new Solicitud_Actualizar_Producto(nombre_articulo,texto_margen_utilidad, texto_unidad_manejo, descripcion_articulo, proveedor, precio_articulo, existencia_articulo, tipo_productop, respoListener);


                            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Modificar_Producto.this);
                            queue.add(solicitud_actualizar_producto);
                        }
                    });
```

Pero no modifica, no hace nada, solo lanza error, en que puedo estarme equivocando? Ayuda por favor. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Estás escribiendo mal la consulta preparada, no debes pasarle los valores, sino poner marcadores, los valores se pasan luego mediante `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`, ese es precisamente el *quid* de las consultas preparadas.

Prueba escribiendo la consulta así, lo haga aparte para que quede más claro:

```
$sql="UPDATE producto SET 
                nombre_producto = ?, 
                margen_utilidad = ?, 
                unidad_manejo = ?, 
                descripcion = ?, 
                proveedor = ?, 
                precio = ?, 
                existencia = ?, 
                tipo_producto = ? 
        WHERE codproducto = ?";

$statement = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql);

//Resto del código
```

**Nótese** que sólo se ponen los marcadores `?`, no se ponen comillas ni nada.

Comment: Me funciona, pero en la apk me da error en android studio

Comment: Lo hice como tu me dices, y probando con varios input me modifica perfecto, pero en android studio me lanza sendo error, ya esto me va hacer matarme jajajaja, pero estoy aprendiendo muchisimo, por favor ayuda COMUNIDAD

Comment: @JoséDaniel ¿qué error da en Android Studio? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y muestra la traza de error completa, así como un Log de lo que estás recibiendo en `response`. Puede que no estés recibiendo un JSON correcto o que no lo estés leyendo bien.